# Variables don't pass to second php

Tags: php

I have 3 php files: the first with a form and its validation, the second that stores those values in the db and the third contains the domain, etc. I have tried everything to pass those variables values from the first to second php ex: `$_POST` , `$_Get` and `isset()` as display in the `Save.php`.

But the values are " " or `null` (empty) because I echo them in the `Save.php` and nothing appears. Just gives me messages for each variable as follows - `Notice: Undefined index: lname in C:\xampp\blablabla\Save.php on line 5`.

The connection is working, the query is working, the validation is working, the form is working. The only problem is when I call

```
if($valid)
{
    header('Location: Save.php');
    exit();
}
```

**main.php**

```
 <?php
 $nombreErr = "";
 $nombre = "";
 $apellidoErr = "";
 $apellido = "";
 $motivosErr = "";
 $motivos = "";
 $idEstudianteErr = "";
 $idEstudiante = "";
 $segundoAppellidoErr = "";
 $segundoAppellido = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $valid = true;
    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) //Nombre Requerido y Solo letras y espacios en blanco
    {
        $nombreErr = "Nombre requerido"; 
        $valid = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $nombre = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$nombre)) 
        {
            $nombreErr = "Solo letras y espacios en blanco"; 
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) //Apellido Requerido y Solo letras y espacios en blanco
    {
        $apellidoErr = "Apellido Requerido";
        $valid = false;
    }
    else 
    {

        $apellido = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$apellido)) 
        {
            $nombreErr = "Solo letras y espacios en blanco"; 
            $valid = false;
        }

    }

    if (empty($_POST["Slname"])) //Segundo apellido solo letras y espacios en blanco
    {
        $segundoAppellido = "";
        $valid = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $segundoAppellido = test_input($_POST["Slname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$segundoAppellido)) 
        {
            $segundoAppellidoErr = "Solo letras y espacios en blanco"; 
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["studentId"])) //Numero estudiante solo numeros y rayas
    {
        $idEstudianteErr= "";
        $valid = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $idEstudiante = test_input($_POST["studentId"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9-]*$/",$idEstudiante)) 
        {
            $idEstudianteErr = "Solo numeros y \"-\""; 
            $valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["Motive"])) //Motivos Requeridos
    {
        $motivosErr = "Motivo(s) Requerido(s)";
        $valid = false;
    } 
    if($valid)
    {
        header('Location: Save.php');
        exit();
    }
}
 function test_input($data) {
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
 }
 ?>

 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="depName" value="Admisiones">
            <input type="hidden" name="personStat" value="Espera">

            <class="input1">FirstName :<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $nombreErr;?></span> <br>

            <class="input2">LastName :<input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $apellido;?>">
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $apellidoErr;?></span> <br>

            <class="input3">Second LastName :<input type="text" name="Slname" value="<?php echo $segundoAppellido; ?>"> 
            <span class="error"><?php echo $segundoAppellidoErr; ?></span> <br>

            <class="input4">Student Id :<input type="text" name="studentId" value="<?php echo $idEstudiante;?>">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $idEstudianteErr; ?></span> <br>


            <select name="Motive[]" multiple="MULTIPLE">

                <?php 
                    $sql1="SELECT categoryName, estimationTime FROM Category where depName='Asistencia Economica'";

                    $result1=mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

                    while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
                    {
                        echo"<option value=".str_replace(" ", "_", $row1['categoryName']) .":". $row1['estimationTime'].">".$row1['categoryName']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <span class="error">* <?php echo $motivosErr;?></span> <br>

            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Registrate">

        </form>
```

**Save.php**

```
 <?php
 include('Connection.php');

 $firstname = isset($_POST['fname']);
 $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,  $_POST['lname']);
 $secondLastName = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['Slname']);
 $studentId =mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['studentId']);
 $depNum= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['depName']);
 $status= $_POST['personStat'];
 $mymotives= $_GET['Motive'];
 $motivestring= "";
 $motiveTime= 0;
 echo $firstname . "where are you";
 echo $lastname;
 echo $secondLastName;
 echo $studentId;
 echo $depNum;
 echo $status;
 echo $mymotives;
 if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

$sql ="INSERT INTO List (depName, personName, personLast, secondLast, stuId, personStatus, manyMotive, categoryTime) 
VALUES ('$depNum','$firstname','$lastname', '$secondLastName','$studentId', '$status', '$motivestring', '$motiveTime')";

 if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
 echo "New record created successfully";
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
 }

 mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where it is not working:

```
Header('Location: Save.php');
```

Here you pass control to Save.php, *but you do not pass any data*... directly. Since it does not work, I gather you're not passing it at all.

You can do one of these things:

- if the file that has executed so far *has not produced any output*, then you can simply `include` the file Save.php:

  include "Save.php"
- if you want to pass data directly and it's not a large amount, you can put it in the GET string, but beware, *it will appear in clear in the address bar*:

  Header("Location: Save.php?name=Vitruvio&surname=Pietrisco&age=67");
- if you want to pass a larger amount of data, you can use **sessions**.

  In the first file:

  session_start(); // The very first line

  ...

  $_SESSION['Hello'] = "World";

  In the second file (Save.php):

  session_start();

  echo "You said " . $_SESSION['Hello'];

  will echo 'You said World'.

**Update**: normally, you would place the validation in the same file that does the save. Or if you want to decouple the sources, you could wrap all the information in an array, and pass it to a function called Save(). This function could be the only function in the Save.php file. Now you can do:

```
$data['firstname'] = $_POST['fname'];
$data['lastname']  = $_POST['lname'];

// Now you could even put $_SESSION['data'] = $data;
// and have it all in the session!

...and also simplify the use of mysql escaping with a cycle:

foreach ($data as $field => $content) {
    $data[$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($con, $content);
}
// By the way: IMPORTANT!. mysql_* functions are DEPRECATED and will be REMOVED
// (maybe soon). Use PDO instead! It takes a bit to adapt, but it's worth it.

if ($valid) {
    // The file is only included if it is necessary, if data are $valid.
    include "Save.php";
    save($data);
}
```

Comment: I used the include it said: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare test_input() (previously declared in C:\xampp\blablal in line 108. And the second option its not safe (personal info). The third...i dont know how to use sessions can you help me with that.

Comment: @MikeAngel You can only have your `function test_input()` declared on one page, so if you are including it on the first page, then also on the included page, you just remove it from the 2nd included page. You can still use it as  `test_input($data)`, you just can't declare it again.

Comment: Don't understand the redeclaration error. Is it OK if I post what would be my approach? It's not too different, and I'll leave out the PDO part.

Comment: I think you probably will help them out a lot if you post a better way to do it, preferably with comments so they know what and why you are doing what you are doing...

Comment: Now i am worry about my code because of the mysql... its the only one i know i am new to php. And i am trying to validad the information a person input and then if its ok save it to the db. I dont know where to put things i am just guessing.

Comment: I surely shall, but not tonight. It's 0300 in my time zone ;-)

Comment: I place all three in one! The validation, the main.php and the save query in the same php and it work. Is that a good practice? or am i doing something not safe or wrong?

Comment: It is good, and for small queries or things you do only once in your app, it is OK. When things will grow more complicated you will want to keep HTML and code separated, as in templating, and your validation functions somewhere else altogether.

Comment: Also i am having the problem if the person click the 'back' button or refresh it will show the personal information of the last form. How can i delete this info in these two cases? Because i only want to preserving the info in the validation process.